# How to return boolean if record exists for multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to return boolean value if the record exists. 
The below query works fine for single table.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(componentid) IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
table3 FROM table3 WHERE componentid = 'GetAccountBalance';
```

I have tried the same for 3 tables using JOIN but I couldn't achieve the expected result.The below query returns all the values as "No" if any of the table (suppose table3) doesn't have record while the other two table has.

```
select CASE WHEN MAX(a.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table1,
CASE WHEN MAX(b.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table2,
CASE WHEN MAX(c.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table3
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.componentid=b.componentid 
join table3 c on a.componentid=c.componentid 
and a.componentid ='GetAccountBalance';
```

Output

```
table1 table2 table3
NO     NO     NO
```

expected

```
table1 table2 table3
YES    YES    NO
```

Also would it be possible to search for multiple values using in? like

```
a.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance')
```

Comment: If you JOIN tables you can't do a MAX on every single table in your sql. The tables are JOINED together and you have a merged result. Simply: Your MAX-Operator is wrong here. You should split this up into seperate SQLs. Have you ever used JOIN before?

Comment: is `componentid` unique in each table? Is it possible that the value does not exist in `table1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 'yes' for both of your question.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should phrase this as `exists`:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 where componentid = 'GetAccountBalance')
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable1,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 where componentid = 'GetAccountBalance')
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable2,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table3 where componentid = 'GetAccountBalance')
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable3
from dual;
```

The overhead of doing joins is simply unnecessary.  The above should also make optimal use of indexes on the tables.

EDIT:

For multiple components, you can use correlated subqueries:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.componentid = c.componentid)
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable1,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.componentid = c.componentid)
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable2,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table3 t3.where t3.componentid = c.componentid)
             then 'YES' else 'NO'
        end) as flagTable3
from (select 'GetAccountBalance' as componentid from dual union all
      select 'GetCreditBalance' from dual
     ) c
```

Comment: @Surya Just use a union to get more than one component.

Answer (score 1):

You want an outer join on all three tables. You also need to include a condition that checks the presence of the value in all three tables:

```
select coalesce(a.componentid, b.componentid, c.componentid) as componentid,
       case when a.componentid is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as in_table1,
       case when b.componentid is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as in_table2,
       case when c.componentid is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as in_table3
from table1 a
  full outer join table2 b on a.componentid = b.componentid
  full outer join table3 c on b.componentid = c.componentid
where a.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance')
   or b.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance')
   or c.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance');
```

If you only use `where a.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance')` the result would not have *any* rows if the values didn't exist at all in `table1`.

This will not return rows for values that are in none of the tables at all!

If `componentid` is **not** unique in each table, you might get multiple rows for each table.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c70b3e/1 
<sup>(The example uses numbers for componentid because I was too lazy to type the strings)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below query:

```
select CASE WHEN MAX(a.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table1,
CASE WHEN MAX(b.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table2,
CASE WHEN MAX(c.componentid)IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END table3
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.componentid=b.componentid 
left outer join table3 c on a.componentid=c.componentid 
and a.componentid ='GetAccountBalance';
```

Yes you can use : `and a.componentid in ('GetAccountBalance','GetCreditBalance')`

It will help you.